# Convert negative datetime to NaT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns: "asked" and "answered", but "answered' is an object while "asked" is a datetime64[ns]. So I convert 'answered' to Datetime:

```
df['answered'] = pd.to_datetime(df['answered'])

index,  asked,    answered
0     2016-07-04  07/07/2016
1     2016-07-03  07/01/2016
2     2016-07-05  07/09/2016
3     NaT         NaN
```

Then, I made a 3rd column that gives me the difference in time between the two:

```
df['Days']= df['answered'] - df['asked']

 index,     asked,    answered,    Days     
    0     2016-07-04  07/07/2016   3 days
    1     2016-07-03  07/01/2016   -2 days
    2     2016-07-05  07/09/2016   4
    3     NaT         NaN          NaT
```

With the help of @piRSquared, I was trying to turn the negative Days into a NaT, but nothing happened when I did this:

```
df.update(df[['Days']].mask(df < 0))
```

**How can I turn the negative days to a NaT?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works comapre `Series` (columns) by `0 Timedelta`, then create `NaT` by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df['Days'] < pd.Timedelta(0)
df['Days'] = df['Days'].mask(mask)
print (df)
       asked   answered   Days
0 2016-07-04 2016-07-07 3 days
1 2016-07-03 2016-07-01    NaT
2 2016-07-05 2016-07-09 4 days
3        NaT        NaT    NaT
```

Or:

```
mask = df['Days'] < pd.Timedelta(0)
df.loc[mask, 'Days'] = np.nan
print (df)
       asked   answered   Days
0 2016-07-04 2016-07-07 3 days
1 2016-07-03 2016-07-01    NaT
2 2016-07-05 2016-07-09 4 days
3        NaT        NaT    NaT
```

But if compare `0 Timedelta` with `DataFrame` it is buggy:

```
print (df)
       asked   answered    Days   Days2
0 2016-07-04 2016-07-07  3 days  3 days
1 2016-07-03 2016-07-01 -2 days -2 days
2 2016-07-05 2016-07-09  4 days  4 days
3        NaT        NaT     NaT     NaT

df1 = df.select_dtypes([np.timedelta64])

#return wrong mask
m1 = df1 < pd.Timedelta(0)
print (m1)
    Days  Days2
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3   True   True

#if comapre with apply by Series it works
m2 = df1.apply(lambda x: x < pd.Timedelta(0))
print (m2)
    Days  Days2
0  False  False
1   True   True
2  False  False
3  False  False

#compare numpy array works but warning 
m3 = df1.values < np.array(0, dtype=np.timedelta64)
print (m3)
[[False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]]
```

> FutureWarning: In the future, 'NAT < x' and 'x < NAT' will always be False.

```
df[df1.columns] = df1.mask(m2)
print (df)
       asked   answered   Days  Days2
0 2016-07-04 2016-07-07 3 days 3 days
1 2016-07-03 2016-07-01    NaT    NaT
2 2016-07-05 2016-07-09 4 days 4 days
3        NaT        NaT    NaT    NaT
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael I've been working on this for hours. Your solution and detailed explanation really helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
df.mask(df < 0)

         Days    col2
index                
0     20 days     NaT
1     61 days 78 days
2         NaT 10 days
```

---

`pd.DataFrame.mask` takes an array of booleans that identify the positions to mask.  If the optional second parameter is passed, it will replace the values in the identified positions with the value(s) specified in the optional parameter.  If that parameter is not passed, as in my proposed solution, then the identified values are replaced with a null value.  Since the `dtypes` of these columns are `timedelta` the appropriate null value will be `NaT`.

---

Suppose your dataframe consist of many columns.  You can focus on just the specific columns you care about.

```
df[['Days', 'col2']].mask(df < 0)
```

And then you can update df inplace with

```
df.update(df[['Days', 'col2']].mask(df < 0))
```

Suppose you wanted to grab all columns that were timedelta

```
df.select_dtypes([np.timedelta]).mask(df < 0)
```

and update

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes([np.timedelta64]).mask(df < 0))
```

Comment: I get "invalid type comparison". Is it because I have more columns that only these two that I put here? I tried this but to no avail: df.mask(df['Days'] < 0)

Comment: still not working for some reason. When I print out the negative dates, I get: "-5 days +00:00:00". The solution you offered doesn't throw an error but it doesn't turn the negative into a NaT. Can there be any other solution to this problem?

Comment: @AdamSchroeder what is the dtype?  df.Days.dtype

Comment: I got this: <class 'pandas.tslib.Timedelta'>

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I got this: dtype('<m8[ns]')

Comment: @AdamSchroeder at this point, you'll have to provide a working example. Edit your post and include code that creates a sample dataframe and demonstrates the problem. This acts to remove any ambiguity. With the information we have so far, I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work. It must be that the dataframe you have isn't exactly like the example you gave.

Comment: @AdamSchroeder ahh! Ok. Convert them to Timedeltas with pd.to_timedelta

Comment: they are as pandas.tslib.Timedelta'. I'm not sure what you're referring to??? I tried to convert like this but it doesn't change anything: 
 df['Days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Days']). I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'll try to update my original post with more info.

Comment: @AdamSchroeder that's correct. Then I'm still confused about what the problem is. That means you need to provide what we call a minimal and complete verifiable example. Or MCVE. Read this to better understand http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Why do this?  Because we are missing something. This exercise will help to eliminate any confusion.

Comment: thank you for your explanation on dataframe.mask. I read it on the pandas website but couldn't understand. Now I got it. I appreciate it.